# Connected to the internet, but I have no access

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, internet

Two days ago, I was on the internet, and then I suddenly lost connection. The icon on the right of my task bar shows that I am connected, and when I called my provider, she said that I'm connected too. Now two days later, I was able to access the internet again for just a short moment, but then I lost connection again. I tried using Chrome, Opera, and Internet Explorer, and I can't get online, and there is no connection problem being detected. How is this possible? It feels like there is someone on the other end disconnecting me, and it's driving me crazy.

I use a Windows 8 laptop. I have wireless connection and I use a router for my internet. I do also have a cable for the internet that is being used. Other computers and phones are able to connect, so I assume it's a problem with my computer. No problems were detected with the troubleshooter.

I should probably also add that I followed advice from a few people to help speed up my computer (in case any of this messed it up). I did the following:

- Deleted all %temp% files
- Deleted all files in Prefetch folder
- I followed many of the steps from this web page 
  http://www.wikihow.com/Speed-Up-a-Slow-Windows-Computer-for-Free
- I followed the steps from this video 
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1I792ze86c

Comment: Did you try anything OTHER than a browser and domain names?  IE: Can you ping sites by IP address? Can you ping your router?

Comment: try power cycling your router/modem?

Comment: Try System Restore back to 3 days ago when it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Every now and then I lose my internet connection and have to go to a command prompt and type `ipconfig /renew` to get it back.  Once I had to type `ipconfig /release` first.  Not sure what causes it, but the fix is easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

First like Saggio said, cycle your modem then router. Unplug the Modem and router, Wait 30 seconds, Plug the modem back in, Wait 30 seconds, Plug the Router in. After this wait and see if you can connect, If not then we have now ruled out the modem and router, (for now). Also I read that you were able to use a direct Ethernet cable for a lan connection, Was that able to connect you to the internet using the cable? Also I would try not to get too lost trying to "speed up your computer" when the problem is internet connection.